# OpenLayers Inconsistent Hit Detection on MVT Layer Hover Selection

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geocoding, openlayers-6, vector-tiles

#### The objective

I'm trying to replicate the "singleselect-hover" feature in [this example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-tile-selection.html) from the OpenLayers site.

#### The issue

When I tried to use this implementation, the hit detection was very poor with `vtLayer.getFeatures(event.pixel)`. The [documentation for the function](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_layer_VectorTile-VectorTileLayer.html) states:

> The hit detection algorithm used for this method is optimized for performance, but is less accurate than the one used in map.getFeaturesAtPixel()

Indeed, when I switched to `map.getFeaturesAtPixel`, the performance increased, but the features still does not work entirely as expected.

When I move my pointer over a vector boundary from the outside, it (usually) behaves as expected:

[image: Expected behavior]

However, when I move to an adjacent boundary and then back, the feature no longer works:

[image: Unexpected behavior]

#### My code:

```js
proj4.defs(
  'EPSG:6931',
  '+proj=laea +lat_0=90 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs'
);
register(proj4);
const projection = get('EPSG:6931');

const osm = new OSM();

const map = new Map({
  target: something,
  layers: [osm],
  view: new View({
    projection: projection,
    zoom: 5,
  }),
})

// Vector Styles
const unselectedStyle = new Style({
  stroke: new Stroke({
    color: 'rgba(50,50,50,0.9)',
    width: 1.2,
  }),
});
const selectedStyle = new Style({
  stroke: new Stroke({
    color: 'white',
    width: 2,
  }),
  fill: new Fill({
    color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)',
  }),
});

const createVtLayer = () => {
  const vtSource = new VectorTileSource({
    tileGrid: new TileGrid({
      extent: [
        -9009964.761231285, -9009964.761231285, 9009964.761231285,
        9009964.761231285,
      ],
      tileSize: 256,
      resolutions: [70390.34969711941],
    }),
    projection: projection,
    format: new MVT({ idProperty: 'some_id' }),
    url:
      geoserverUrl +
      '/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/' +
      mvtLayerName +
      '@EPSG%3A' +
      projection.getCode().split(':')[1] + // EPSG number of current projection
      '@pbf/{z}/{x}/{-y}.pbf',
  });

  return new VectorTileLayer({
    zIndex: 1,
    source: vtSource,
    style: unselectedStyle,
  });
};

const vtLayer = createVtLayer();

// Local lookup for highlighted features
let selection = null;
const selectionLayer = new VectorTileLayer({
  zIndex: 2,
  source: vtLayer.getSource(),
  style: feature => feature === selection && selectedStyle,
});

if (map && vtLayer && selectionLayer) {
  // Add layers to map once loaded into state
  map.addLayer(vtLayer);
  map.addLayer(selectionLayer);

  // Update styling of selectionLayer on mouse hover
  map.on(['pointermove', 'click'], event => {
    // Send vector metadata to parent component on mouse click
    if (event.type === 'click' && selection) {
      onFeatureSelect(selection);
    }
    map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(
      event.pixel,
      feature => {
        selection = feature;
      }, {
        layerFilter: layer => layer === vtLayer,
        hitTolerance: 1,
      }
    );
    selectionLayer.changed()
  });
}
```

#### What I've tried so far

I've tried adjusting the `renderBuffer` and `renderMode` parameters in the VectorTile layer, as well as adjusting the `hitTolerance` option in `map.forEachFeatureAtPixel`, and I haven't had any luck yet. When I logged the feature id from the feature parameter in forEachFeatureAtPixel, I noticed something strange--when the unexpected behavior occurs, after dragging the pointer over an adjacent boundary line, the selected variable rapidly switches between the two features and assigns the undesired one, until I touch the pointer to a non-adjacent boundary line. Modifying the `hitTolerance` only causes the selected feature to switch more frequently.

[image: console logging selected features and feature id from forEachFeatureAtPixel parameter]

#### Theories and questions

I'm thinking that maybe my adjacent vectors are overlapping each others boundaries? Or maybe there is a problem with the way the vectors are loaded as MVTs?

Comment: Features can be split across tile boundaries.  The example relies on them having an idProperty which is the same on all tiles  Also as you have two layers forEachFeatureAtPixel will need a layerFilter.

Comment: @Mike -- Thanks for the response. I made some adjustments but unfortunately the problem persists. I added some info on the selected feature being logged to the console if that helps to clarify anything.

Comment: I think it may e because your unselectedStyle does not have a fill.  Undefined fill is not hit detected, but you can specify a fully transparent fill to get hit detection inside a polygon outline.

Comment: @Mike Thank you! That worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding an invisible `Fill()` to the unselectedStyle allowed the layer to be hit-detected and solved my issue!

```js
// Vector Styles
const unselectedStyle = new Style({
  stroke: new Stroke({
    color: 'rgba(50,50,50,0.9)',
    width: 1.2,
  }),
  fill: new Fill({
    color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
  }),
});
```

Thanks Mike!